# How can i comparer HKL and char[]?

Tags: c++, char, compare

I have

```
DWORD dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
HKL hCurKeyboard = GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadID);
```

that return HKL current keyboard i need compare it with some char

```
char defaultLanguage[64]="0x04090409";
```

How can i compare HKL `hCurKeyboard` with `defaultLanguage`

or How can i create some HKL with this value `"0x04090409"`

```
        char defaultLanguageLayout[64] = "0x04090409";
        DWORD dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
        HKL hCurKeyboard = GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadID);
//->>       if(hCurKeyboard!=defaultLanguageLayout) 
        {

            UINT i;
            HKL hklCurrent;
            UINT uLayouts;
            HKL * lpList;

            uLayouts = GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, NULL);
            lpList = (HKL*) malloc(uLayouts * sizeof(HKL));
            uLayouts = GetKeyboardLayoutList(uLayouts, lpList);

            for(i=0; i<uLayouts; i++)
            {
                hklCurrent = *(lpList + i);

//->>               if(hklCurrent == defaultLanguageLayout){
                    ActivateKeyboardLayout(hklCurrent, 0);
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the _type_ of `defaultLanguage`.

Comment: Where did `"0x04090409"` come from?  Did you type that in your code, or does it come from a file/user/internet?

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood the documentation.  So it's a string literal you typed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305(v=vs.85).aspx, the best thing to do is something like:

```
    HKL defaultLanguageLayout = LoadKeyboardLayout("0x04090409", KLF_SUBSTITUTE_OK);
    DWORD dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
    HKL hCurKeyboard = GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadID);
    if(hCurKeyboard!=defaultLanguageLayout) {
```

But I don't understand Keyboard layouts enough to know if the second parameter is correct.

Comment: @Sasha: [Cicida says you can just cast it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4048672#4048672), try that?